# How does Jekyll apply `include` outside of `<body>` tag?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

While digging deeper into Jekyll and Bootstrap, I noticed something about the Liquid tags used to include partials.

I placed a `{% include footer.html %}` outside of `</body>`, and lo-and-behold, the footer was rendered *within* the body tag!

I had placed a Bootstrap specific border class on the body, and was expecting to see the border exclude the footer, which is how I discovered this nuance.

I think it's obvious that something outside of the `<body>` would/should not be rendered.... but this is a Liquid include tag. Somehow `{% include head.html %}` *IS* rendered on the page, and is appearing where it should...above the body tag with the usual fodder and markup.

So what's going on here? What's the convention?

I looked through the Jekyll docs, which are excellent, but make no allusion to how these include tags are parsed.

I also searched through various questions here, though those are more looking for help with basic rendering, or advanced variable passing.

I also did a google search, but my googlefu came up short...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll does nothing special to `{% include %}`-s anywhere. If you put an `{% include %}` directive outside a `<body>` tag, the included content will also stay outside the tag. If you inspect the generated files, e.g. by opening one with a text editor, you'll see everything as expected.

It is, however, **your browser** that moves such content back to inside the `<body>` tag, as such content will otherwise be invalid HTML.

Comment: thanks for the answer! This doesn't necessarily explain how the browser knows to exclude the <head> tag....unless the browser is "intelligent" enough to know it doesn't need to move that markup